# How to redefine a variable on content page's codebehind that was declared on master page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, visual-studio-2010, code-behind

I am building a web application using VS2010 and ASP.NET 4

I have managed to declare and define a variable in a nested master page and call it within the master page. However, **how do I change the value of that variable from a content page's codebehind**?

Here are the variable declarations from DeckNav.master.cs (nested master page codebehind):

```
public partial class DeckNav : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.mfrName = "(BRAND)";
        this.modelName = "(MODEL)";
    }

    public string mfrName { get; set; }
    public string modelName { get; set; }
}
```

This is how I call the 2 variables (default values) in master page (DeckNav.master):

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="brandAndModel" runat="server">
<h1 class="page-header"> <%= mfrName %> <%= modelName %>
</h1>
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

In the content page inherited from DeckNav.master, I need to know how to change the values of the variables accordingly for each ASPX content page from the codebehind.

Example:

```
public partial class DeckRepair : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mfrName = "Brand 10";
        modelName = "Model 12";          
    }

}
```

The snippet above does not work. Visual Studio alerts me that "The name  does not exist in the current context".

---

EDIT:

I declared the variables as static on the master page's codebehind to:

```
public partial class LeftNav : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    public static string camMfr { get; set; }
    public static string camModel { get; set; }
}
```

... and assigned values on the content page's codebehind:

```
public partial class BrandModel : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LeftNav.camMfr = "BRAND 11";
        LeftNav.camModel = "MODEL 11";
    }
}
```

I'm still having the same problem. It successfully assigns the variable the first time to "BRAND 11", but when I load another content page with its own unique values for camMfr and camModel (i.e. "BRAND 22" , "MODEL 22") it retains the original assigned value ("BRAND 11"). Keep in mind I am NOT assigning a value in the master page, only declaring it.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
DeckNav.mfrName = "Brand 10";
DeckNav.modelName = "Model 12";
```

Comment: Thank you. I had to change the strings to static.

That kind of worked. I managed to change the string's value once using this method. I created more content pages and set unique values for the strings mfrName and modelName and the unwanted string values are still showing when I run the Web Application.

I want the master page to have a variable (string) that appears on content pages, but the strings value will change according to how it's set on the content pages' codebehind.

Comment: Well, the main problem is that you are assigning values to them on the page load for the master page.  Every time you navigate to a new page, they are being set to those values.  You should just declare them in the master page and assign values to them in you content pages.